# Flex application font style is different between Flash Builder and MXMLC

Tags: apache-flex, flash, mxmlc

When I compile my project with MXMLC I get a light grey font; if I specify a CSS style `Application { color: black;}` it fixes some of the colors but not most of them. When I compile with Flash Builder it's a nice solid black. I'm using Halo.swc and not any Spark stuff, I have the same fonts installed on the MXMLC compiling computer, same SDK, so is Flash Builder using a stylesheet somewhere or something I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have mentioned I'm using Flash Builder's 3.5 compiler instead of 4.0 since the project is old, and my command line SDK is 4.0 only with a compatibility version = 3.5 flag passed in. Anyway, the command line version is nevertheless using the modern 4.0 Halo theme while Flash Builder is using the classic Halo theme for 3.5, which is where the difference is. (Changing the project to 4.0 in flash builder results in the same look as the command line.)

Comment: Furthermore, a few existing styles I had were un-namespaced and Flex 4 demands otherwise. Add `@namespace mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml";` to the top and `mx|` in front of all the old styles. It's now just a matter of finding little inconsistencies inside a couple more components but now it's all good again.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your global styles into a global selector at the top of your stylesheet, like so:

```
global {
  /* styles */
}
```